# Como podria Cargar JavaScript o CSS dinamicamente PHP?

Tags: php

Hola estoy intentando crear una clase  con un método en el cual pueda cargar js y css dinámicamente.

> el problema es : ya que algunos documentos PHP se encuentra en la carpeta raiz  y otros se encuentran en una sub-carpeta, la ruta del archivo  js cambia dependiendo de donde este llamando.
>   alagunos debo agregarle "../"  y en otros casos no debo agregarle.

ya que la lista de archivos JS es extensa y se **repite** en casi todas las paginas del sistema

He creado un array con todos los nombre delos documentos .js que debo llamar

```html
         $ListaJs =array(
                'modernizr.min.js',
                'retina.js',
                'tmpl.min.js',
                'load-image.min.js',
                'canvas-to-blob.min.js',
                'jquery.iframe-transport.min.js',
                'jquery.fileupload.min.js',
                'jquery.fileupload-fp.min.js',
                'jquery.fileupload-ui.min.js',
                'jquery.fileupload-init.js',
                'jquery.timeago.js',
                'jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
                'jquery.autosize-min.js',
                'charCount.js',

            );
```

Así está distribuidas mi carpeta (**todos los js se encuentras en la carpeta asset/javascript**)

```html
--assets
----img
----javascript
----css
--clases
----cargar.php
--sistema
----login.php
--index.php
```

en el documento cargar.php tengo el siguiente código

```html
class cargar {

  private $direccion ;

  function __construct(){
        $this->direccion = dirname(__DIR__);
   }

    public function loadJS(){

        $ListaJs =array(
            'modernizr.min.js',
            'retina.js',
            'tmpl.min.js',
            'load-image.min.js',
            'canvas-to-blob.min.js',
            'jquery.iframe-transport.min.js',
            'jquery.fileupload.min.js',
            'jquery.fileupload-fp.min.js',
            'jquery.fileupload-ui.min.js',
            'jquery.fileupload-init.js',
            'jquery.timeago.js',
            'jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
            'jquery.autosize-min.js',
            'charCount.js',

        );

        $script = "";
        foreach ($ListaJs as $key => $value) {
            //$direccion =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $script .= "<script src='". $this->direccion  ."/assets/javascripts/" .$value ." type='text/javascript'></script> </br>";
        }

       return $script;

    }
}
```

y llamo la funcion ya sea en index.php o en login.php para cargar los JS en la pagina ( **no se si este bien utilizar Echo "";** )

```html
 // pido que se importe la clase cargar
 require_once('clases/cargar.php');
 // instancio la clase
    $test = new cargar;
 // llamo la funcion
    $datos = $test->loadJS();
 //imprimo los js
    echo $datos;
```

me muestra el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podría solucionar el error he probado inicializando la variable `$direccion` desde el constructor con  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: ¿qué es diatónicamente?

Comment: Perdona auto corrector "dinámicamente"

Comment: Según lo que entiendo tratas de cargar un documento o script de PHP según dada una condición (a esto te refieres con cargarlo dinámicamente), mi pregunta sería ¿has probado hacerlo con un SWITCH?

Comment: No estoy tratando de cargar un script de PHP estoy tratando de cargar varios archivos JS  desde una  clase PHP . ya que este código se repite en todo el proyecto

Comment: No estoy tratando de cargar un script de PHP estoy tratando de cargar varios archivos JS  desde una  clase PHP . ya que este código se repite en todo el proyecto

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que Google Chrome bloquea el acceso a archivos locales por seguridad, no es un error de PHP, aquí tiene un artículo que lo explica: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Tienes chances de cargarlos con su ruta relativa en lugar de absoluta? Tal vez eso solucione tu problema. También ayudaría a mejorar mi respuesta si me muestra el código fuente de la parte  dinámica para ver exactamente como estás cargando cada archivo desde el código fuente generado con php.

Comment: Hola Pedro Gracias por contestar he modificado la pregunta. tal-vez este un poco mas clara para que me ayudes a solucionar.

no se si funcione lo de cargar por la ruta relativa ya que dependiendo  de donde llame la clase la ruta relativa cambia ( podria se llamada desde el directorio raiz  o una subcarpeta)  en todo caso dependera el caso la ruta llevaria   " ../ "  o no

Comment: Podrías por favor copiar y pegar en tu pregunta la parte del código fuente generado para que me de una idea de cómo esta saliendo? Básicamente una ruta del tipo: "archivo.js" o "../js/archivo.js" o "js/archivo.js" funcionará, sin embargo "C:/miproyecto/js/archivo.js" no funcionará

Comment: He recreado ru situación en mi servidor y lo primero que noto es que te falta una comilla de cierre en esta porción de código: foreach ($ListaJs as $key => $value) {
            //$direccion =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $script .= "<script src='". $this->direccion  ."/assets/javascripts/" .$value ." type='text/javascript'></script> </br>";
        }

Como verás tienes una comilla simple de apertura luego de <script src= pero esta comilla debería cerrarse luego de ."/assets/javascripts/" .$value ."  >> así ."/assets/javascripts/" .$value ."'

Para empezar corrige eso.

Comment: Vale al final tu concejo me ha servido mucho.  con las de las rutas dinamicas